# Ruby Unit test - Instance variable declared in setUp takes value nil

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

Hello I have a trouble with Ruby unit testing, I'm new to it so some help would be lovely

```
class TestItem < Test::Unit::TestCase
 def setUp
  **@item**=Item.new('Food','Burger',120)
 end
 def testGetType
  assert_equal(**@item**.getType,'Food')
 end
end
```

Here the value of instance variable @item takes **nil** when I declare it in setUp() and use it in test functions! So I get an error like no method 'getType' for nil-class

But when I directly use it like assert_equal(Item.new('Food','Burger',120).getType,'Food'),it works fine.

Please point out to my mistakes, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the `setup` method is `setup`, not `setUp`. In fact, you will *never* find a method called `setUp` in Ruby, since the standard Ruby style for method naming is `snake_case`, not `camelCase`. (The same applies to `getType` and `testGetType`, BTW. It should be `get_type` and `test_get_type`. Well, actually, in Ruby, getters aren't prefixed with `get`, so really it should be `type` and `test_type`. But note that in Ruby, all objects already have `type` method, although that is deprecated.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm from python background so.. Thanks mate :)